# How to ignore a run.js in Angular / Karma unit testing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I have a file `run.js` that has:

```
window.map.run([
    '$rootScope', '$location', 'cache', 'userCache',
    function($rootScope, $location, cache, userCache) {
        userCache.checkSession().then(function(result) {
            if(result.userId) {
                cache.set('login', 'successfulLogin', true);
                if($location.path() !== '/patients') {
                    $location.path('/patients');
                }
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

This runs when the app loads. This is normally great behavior. But when I'm unit testing controllers, all hell breaks loose. I can't figure out how to `spy` or `mock` this so that it's false. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You can break your app up into multiple angular modules. Put the run block on your root module and only load the child modules you need in the unit tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude `run.js` by specifying the relevant pattern in [karma.conf](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html) file

```
**/!(run).js
```

Or you could split you app in smaller modules and load only the relevant modules during unit test.